# How can I trigger a Capistrano task from a different namespace than :deploy?

Tags: ruby, deployment, capistrano

In my capistrano recipe, I have a namespace with different tasks:

```
namespace :mystuff do
  task :mysetup do; ... end;
  task :mytask1 do; ... end;
  task :mytask2 do; ... end;
  task :mycleanup do; ... end;
end
```

These customised tasks are triggered via lines like this at the top of my recipe:

```
after "deploy", "mystuff:mycleanup"
```

I want to execute a normal capistrano task from inside my namespace. For example, I want to automatically trigger the normal cleanup task if a certain number of release folders have built up:

```
task :mycleanup do;
  if releases.length > 50
    logger.info "Too many releases, runing deploy:cleanup."
    deploy:cleanup #***THIS DOESN'T WORK***
  end
end;
```

Unfortunately calling `deploy:cleanup` doesn't work from inside my namespace. How can I execute `deploy:cleanup`?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Aha, the correct syntax is to use a `.`, not a `:`. i.e. `deploy.cleanup`, no `deploy:cleanup`.

This works:

```
task :mycleanup do;
  if releases.length > 50
    logger.info "Too many releases, runing deploy:cleanup."
    deploy.cleanup
  end
end;
```